# Select next value where it equals another value

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause

I have a table of the fiscal year for 100 years. i.e.

[image]

I am wanting to do add a column which shows the fiscal year that each week_ending_date belongs to. So in the table above week number 1, and week_ending_date 2013-10-05 would belong to fiscal year ending 2014.

In short I simply want each value in the added column to be the year part of week_ending_date where the next week_number is 52.

Here would be the pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve.

```
SELECT
    Week_Ending_Date,
    (SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Week_Ending_Date (***but as only year***) FROM Fiscal_Calendar WHERE FC.Week_Number = 52)
FROM Fiscal_Calendar AS FC
JOIN Shipped_Container AS SC
    ON SC.Fiscal_Week_Ending = FC.Week_Ending_Date
```

Bare in mind this has 100 years in the table and so I can't select the last value and makes using WHERE difficult (for me).

Comment: Just verifying - For Week_Ending_Date (which is of the form YYYY-MM-DD) if MM-DD < "10-01", then you want the new column to contain YYYY, otherwise, the new column should contain YYYY+1 ?

Comment: Well yes but because the start of the financial year can vary from year to year that start date of 10-01 might not always be that specific MM-DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is by subtracting 7 * week number, taking the year and adding 1:

```
select 1 + year(dateadd(day, -7 * week_number, week_ending_date))
```